# Create a JLabel dynmaiclly

Tags: java

Hi，there is a problem in my java application, the text in my Jbutton is too long so it only show"..." on the button. Now I want to add some component to help show the actual text on the button.

What method can I use to solve such problem rather than adjusting the text font or button size?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Do you know what a tooltip is and how to use them? You could create the label in advance and later only call `label.setVisible(true)` or `label.setVisible(false)`.

Comment: Hi, since sometimes the number of word in JButton is too long, so it can't show they, and only show "..."

Comment: In your next questions, you should not only describe _what you are doing_ but more importantly _what you want to achieve_ and _what the problem_ is. As you can see in this question, you could have ended up writing lots of unnecessary code, in a case where there is a simple solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a label, you should add a tooltip to the button:

```
jb.setToolTipText("The full text of the button");
```

A small downside is that this tooltip will also be shown if the button text is fully visible, and in that case the tooltip doesn't provide any additional information, which will be confusing. I don't know off my head how to solve this, but it's definitely possible.